# Join Two Table With Matching First Table Row With 2 Rows Of Second Table And Get All 3 Rows In One Line

Tags: mysql, sql, join

My question is a little confusing as I will explain with a simple example. I want to join a table in two columns. For example, Below I have two tables with the given structure.

**Table_01:**

```
ID        Type        Name        Gender
-----------------------------------------
1        Parent    Jhon Cena       Male
2        Tutor       Paige        Female
3        Tutor       Nikki        Female
4        Parent    The Rock        Male
5        Parent    Big Show        Male
6        Tutor       Brie         Female
```

**Table_02:**

```
ID    Tutor_ID    Parent_ID     Name        Gender
----------------------------------------------------
1         2           1        Oliver        Male
2         3           1         Emma        Female
3         3           4        Sophia       Female
4         7           5        George        Male
5         2           4       Isabella      Female
6         6           7        Arthur        Male
```

*Note: The Tutor_ID & Parent_ID columns from Table_02 are the primary key of Table_01 that I have to match.*

Now I want to run a query that will pick the Parent and Tutor of the Child(Table_02) in one row as per the Table_02 rows count and where there is no Parent and Tutor is available then leave the data blank but pickup the child data. The example output should be like this.

**Output:**

```
T2.ID    T2.Name     T2.Gender     T1.ParentName     T1.T1_TutorName
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1        Oliver         Male        Jhon Cena            Paige 
2         Emma         Female       Jhon Cena            Nikki
3        Sophia        Female       The Rock             Nikki
4        George         Male        Big Show           --NULL--
5       Isabella       Female       The Rock             Paige
6        Arthur         Male        --NULL--             Brie
```

So Is this possible or do I have to make two tables for Parents and Tutors that is the worst-case scenario for me.

Comment: "not able to cover my question in words" Please try. Also show any parts you can do & give a [mre]. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)

Comment: "the child count" is clearly not clear, please use enough words. Please try to give a query that gets them. But first, one that gets those children with other relevant data. Etc.

Comment: Question updated with a demo output also.

Comment: Answer added...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ANSWER:

So I tried and here is the answer...

```
SELECT * FROM Table_02 as T2, Table_01 as P, (SELECT * FROM Table_01 WHERE Type = 'Tutor') as T WHERE T2.Parent_ID = P.ID AND T2.Tutor_ID = T.ID;
```

And here is the answer with LEFT JOIN...

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_02 as T2
LEFT JOIN Table_01 as P 
ON T2.Parent_ID = P.ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table_01 WHERE Type = 'Tutor') as T
ON T2.Tutor_ID = T.ID;
```